# Ubuntu 14.04 server interfaces not coming up

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router

I have two ethernet interfaces, `p10p1` (motherboard) and `eth1` (card), and the only interface that is loading on boot is loopback; neither of the Ethernet interfaces are loading. This has started occurring after [unsuccessfully] trying to create a `pppoe` connection and then completely removing `pppoeconf` in an attempt to remove any trace of its effect on the system.

The `/etc/network/interfaces` file is as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p10p1
iface p10p1 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.5.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.5.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

When booting, I get the message “Waiting for network configuration” then ”Waiting an additional 60 seconds for network configuration.”

I can bring up the interfaces manually using `sudo ifconfig p10p1 up` (same for `eth1`), but that doesn’t seem to accomplish anything.

The current configuration is that this server sits behind a router that provides DHCP to the whole network (there are no devices behind the server at this point). `p10p1` interface is the “external/primary” interface and `eth1` is the “internal” interface.

The end goal is to get a `pppoe` connection going to I can turn the unfortunate router my ISP gave me for our fiber internet into bridge mode and make the server the primary gateway/firewall/router again; that’s how it was when we had cable Internet.

For now, though, I just need to get this box communicating with the interwebs again so I can install `rp-pppoe` and try that.

I’m wondering if my uninstall of `pppoeconf` wiped something out, or if in the process of configuring pppoeconf, something was done that might render `/etc/network/interfaces` inoperable. Is that possible?

Any thoughts on why my interfaces are not coming up on boot?

Comment: Well, both interfaces are configured as DHCP clients. Do you have a DHCP server that would listen to DHCP requests?

Comment: Yes, eth1 should be static as the isc-dhcp-server is running on that interface, but at the moment I'm less concerned about it as I am about p10p1. The current router is providing DHCP without any issue for the rest of the network. It was working prior to my attempt at the pppoe connection (not with this interfaces configuration, but of course I didn't save the old one before messing with it).

Comment: Sorry. It is not a PoS router. It is a piece of crap. Well, that's what I've been told anyways. I have edited the post to clarify that. It is a ZyXEL FR1000Z.

Comment: 'ifconfig interface up' only enables the interface, it doesn't configure it. Try 'ifup p10p1' and 'ifup eth1' (and maybe check that gateway for eth1)

Comment: thanks for the tip on `ifup`. The gateway for eth1 is set to the ZyXEL router, otherwise traffic on the server never leaves the server in this situation or something. When it is set to `192.168.5.1`, and you ping Google or something, the host is unreachable. Perhaps there is another workaround, but this is working for the time being. When the server becomes the primary gateway for the network, it will switch to `192.168.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much of an answer this will be as I'm not sure exactly why this worked (so I won't be checking it as the correct answer). There was nothing wrong with the configuration, it seemed to do with the file itself. I created a new file with the exact same parameters, wrote it to the original file name, restarted and boom, the interfaces came up exactly how they are supposed to.

@Brandon's comment about using `ifup` on the interface led me on the path. Prior to overwriting the file, I tried using `ifup p10p1` and I was informed that it could not read the file or some such thing. So I thought maybe the file was corrupt, overwrote it, and now it works.